# How to batch create an embedded index for multiple pdf files?

Tags: pdf, acrobat-pro-dc

I know how to create an embedded index in an opened pdf file using Acrobat Pro DC. However, I need to do this for hundreds of files so doing this manually one by one is not feasible. How can I automate this process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acrobat Pro can do it for entire folders, as follows:

- [Creating Actions using "Action Wizard" in Adobe Acrobat DC](https://www.evermap.com/ActionWizardDC.asp)
  Define this way an action for creating the embedded index.
- The action to automate above will be the one you already know,
  to create the index, as described in:
  [Create and manage an index in a PDF](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/creating-pdf-indexes.html)
- Use the
  [Action Wizard (Acrobat Pro)](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/action-wizard-acrobat-pro.html)
  to run the above action on all the files in the required folder(s),
  as described in the section "Run an action".

Comment: After every completed file I get a 'Click to Proceed' button which I have to click. Is there a way to not get that button showing up?

Comment: I don't know how to avoid this prompt. Perhaps while defining/launching the action there is some checkbox for it, or look in Preferences. (I no longer have Acrobat Pro to test with.)